# Relative and absolute path problems in .net core app when published

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8, kestrel-http-server

I have got this problem with a program when I publish it to the server, the problem arises because it is published to a folder on the server rather than the root.

In the pages there are bits of code like this in the .cshtml files

```
@section head {
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.scss" />
}
```

If I publish this it interprets it as the file being at [www.website.com/css/login.scss](http://www.website.com/css/login.scss) instead of [www.website.com/folder/css/login.scss](http://www.website.com/folder/css/login.scss)

**I tried to use ~ infront of the link but that causes the whole program to crash with an Error 500, logging says this:**

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HM3MGHFA29RH", Request id "0HM3MGHFA29RH:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No files found matching "/folder/css/login.scss" exist in "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\folder\wwwroot\"
```

Adding the ~ makes the program think the file is in the wrong location, I don't know how to resolve this without publishing the project to a root of a website which I want to avoid. I've tried all kinds of methods but am getting nowhere.

Comment: Unfortunately that was one of the things I tried, it then produces an url like this <link rel="stylesheet" href="/./css/login.scss" />

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15112#issuecomment-543631807 Sounds like nothing should be there before `css` (if that works for Blazor it should also work for ASP.NET Core in general).

Comment: Unfortunately that produces the same result as using /css/

Comment: After some testing I think `~/css/login.scss` is still the right way to go (if you generate new projects from `dotnet new mvc` you can see examples). Have you called `IApplicationBuilder.UsePathBase` as required?

Comment: I did not have it but I added app.UsePathBase("/folder"); to startup.cs but it made no difference, same errors and behaviour still.

Comment: I figured out that it's sometihng called WebOptimizer that's causing the problem, it apparently formats and serves the CSS files but doesn't seem to get the hang of the figuring out the proper paths from ~/css/login.scss and so crashses. But if I disable it I get problems with the CSS and JS files not working.

Comment: Converted all the scss files to .css files and served them directly, removed WebOptimizer, JS files seem to be working.